# Uso correcto de entidades de retorno para EntityFramework

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6, orm, automapper

Tengo un proyecto de base de datos (sqlproj) que utilizo para publicar y recrear la base de datos cuando es necesario, y otro proyecto donde estoy utilizando EntityFramework para traer la base de datos y generar el modelo de entidades a partir de ella.

Lo primero que intenté a modo de pruebas, fue retornar un registro de una tabla:

```
    public virtual Users GetUser()
    {
        // Variables Declaration
        Users queryResult;

        // Beg Connection
        using (MyContext = new MyDataBaseEntities())
        {
            // Execution
            queryResult = MyContext.Users.FirstOrDefault();
        }
        // End Connection

        return queryResult;
    }
```

El problema que tuve de inmediato, fue que al intentar retornar el objeto obtenido desde la capa de datos, obtenía un mensaje que decía:

> The operation cannot be completed because the DbContext has been disposed.

Entendí que para devolver correctamente los datos, iba a tener que crear una clase identica a la que generó EntityFramework y así no perder el valor cuando salga del using y el dbContext ejecute el dispose.

Ahora, lo que estoy intentando evitar, es tener que duplicar todas las entidades que genere con EntityFramework sólo para poder devolverlas fuera del contexto de base de datos, además de tener que hacerlo manualmente.

Encontré una solución parcial que me permite generar las mismas entidades utilizando Scaffold-DbContext de la siguiente manera:

> Scaffold-DbContext "Server=localhost;DataBase=MyDataBase;Trusted_Connection=True;" Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -OutputDir Orm\Entities -f

Lo anterior, mapea todas las entidades de EF a la carpeta Orm\Entities y a pesar que igualmente debo realizar ciertos cambios en las entidades generadas, me ahorra bastante tiempo y posiblemente luego pueda utilizar AutoMapper para asignar los datos desde la entidad de EF a estas nuevas entidades (esto último aún no lo pruebo).

Mi pregunta es, ¿Hay algo que no estoy considerando, que quizás podría solucionar de mejor forma mi problema de retornar la información de entidades de EF hacia las otras capas de la solución?

Muchas gracias de antemano

Comment: Hola, podrías indicar en la pregunta tu `DbContext` y la clase `Users`?. Por otra parte estas utilizando .NET Core?

Answer (score 0):

Has probado a devolver el objeto `Users queryResult` antes de que el `DbContext` se destruya?.

Prueba de esta manera:

```
public virtual Users GetUser()
{
    // Variables Declaration
    Users queryResult;

    // Beg Connection
    using (MyDataBaseEntities MyContext = new MyDataBaseEntities())
    {
        // Execution
        queryResult = MyContext.Users.FirstOrDefault();
        return queryResult;
    }
    // End Connection        
}
```

Comment: Si, probé de esta manera, pero obtengo el mensaje que mencionaba arriba:

Comment: The ObjectContext instance has been disposed and can no longer be used for operations that require a connection

Comment: @IsaiasPeñaCromilakis: Ese error es diferente al de arriba no?, ahora te da un error diferente por otras causas. Indica por favor el Modelo `Users` (y sus Modelos relacionados) y tu `DbContext` como te indique antes, por que si no va a ser difícil ayudarte.